# Arranging 2 stacked sub-figures to be next to another subfigure

Tags: graphics, floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I want to arrange my subfigures in this [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGVCG.png) (made from powerpoint) but it turns out like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHgQm.png). Below is the code I have used. How can I make this adjustment.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = small]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0pt}

\begin{figure}[t] %fig1 
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{a.jpg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{b.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{c.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = small]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t] %fig1 
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.52\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{a.jpg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.46\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{b.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\par
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{c.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks! I do not know if this was trivial but I did not see a solution up until now.

Comment: I add a well-deserved +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!